# Cannot enable Hyper-V service with Docker in windows 10

Tags: docker, virtualization, hyper-v

I have already enabled virtualization in my BIOS, and also enabled it in Windows features

[image]

Furthermore, the Android emulator with Android Studio is working well, but when I try to run Docker for Windows, I encounter this problem:

[image]

I don't know where the problem is.

Comment: Try to restart your machine.

Comment: i tried that a lot

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to autostart the hypervisor at startup.

Open a Powershell as Admin (right-click Powershell, click "Run as administrator").
Paste the line:

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto
```

[image]

"bcd" stands for Boot Configuration Data, to set it to automatically launch hypervisor. Then the hypervisor will start at the next boot and it should work.

For future information see:
https://d3v.one/windows-10-changing-hyper-v-support-at-boot-time/

Comment: it is work, thanks, but i encounter another problem :
Docker.Core.HttpBadResponseException:
Unhandled exception: Operation failed with result 4096
   at Docker.Core.Logging.ClientExceptionInterceptor.<InterceptResponseAsync>d__0.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\stable-2.3.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\Logging\ClientExceptionInterceptor.cs:line ...........

Comment: Sorry I'm not that docker pro but there are some Google hits

Answer (score 3):

Just re-enable Hyper-V.

Concrete steps:

- Go to *Apps & features*.
- Select *Programs and Features* on the right under *Related settings*.
- Select *Turn Windows features on or off*.
- **Deselect** *Hyper-V*, and click *OK*. (This disables Hyper-V).
- Restart the computer.

After restart,

- Go to *Apps & features*.
- Select *Programs and Features* on the right under *Related settings*.
- Select *Turn Windows features on or off*.
- **Select** *Hyper-V*, and click *OK*. (This enables Hyper-V).
- Restart the computer.

After restart, docker worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for my team was to make sure Containers and Hyper-V was enabled, then making sure Docker Desktop was updated.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

I tried both options described here without success:

1. Unchecked `Hyper-V` in `Windows feature`(reboot), checked again(reboot)
2. Run `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto` as Administrator in Powershell and reboot the PC

**SOLUTION**: What solved the issue for me was to update the Docker Desktop version (from 3.6 to 4.3)